# Converting Python codes to php

Tags: python, php

In our project we need similarity checker for PHP. I found great codes about it in Python. But I don't have any practical knowledge about Python. Now I need to convert it to PHP or I need to method to integrate Python to Laravel. Which method would be better? And How can I do this?

```
import pygments.token
import pygments.lexers

#Python module pygments is used to tokenize the code files. This module supports most of the popular languages
#http://pygments.org/languages/
#Hence this program can be used to clean up codes written in most languages
def tokenize(filename):
    file = open(filename, "r")
    text = file.read()
    file.close()
    lexer = pygments.lexers.guess_lexer_for_filename(filename, text)
    tokens = lexer.get_tokens(text)
    tokens = list(tokens)
    result = []
    lenT = len(tokens)
    count1 = 0    #tag to store corresponding position of each element in original code file
    count2 = 0    #tag to store position of each element in cleaned up code text
    # these tags are used to mark the plagiarized content in the original code files.
    for i in range(lenT):
        if tokens[i][0] == pygments.token.Name and not i == lenT - 1 and not tokens[i + 1][1] == '(':
            result.append(('N', count1, count2))  #all variable names as 'N'
            count2 += 1
        elif tokens[i][0] in pygments.token.Literal.String:
            result.append(('S', count1, count2))  #all strings as 'S'
            count2 += 1
        elif tokens[i][0] in pygments.token.Name.Function:
            result.append(('F', count1, count2))   #user defined function names as 'F'
            count2 += 1
        elif tokens[i][0] == pygments.token.Text or tokens[i][0] in pygments.token.Comment:
            pass   #whitespaces and comments ignored
        else:
            result.append((tokens[i][1], count1, count2))  
            #tuples in result-(each element e.g 'def', its position in original code file, position in cleaned up code/text) 
            count2 += len(tokens[i][1])
        count1 += len(tokens[i][1])

    return result

def toText(arr):
    cleanText = ''.join(str(x[0]) for x in arr)
    return cleanText
```

Comment: Your codes is for pygments. For PHP you may refer to [PHP_wrapper_for_Pygments](https://github.com/ramsey/pygments). Use the Pygments.php and refer to the documentation please

Comment: Can I run these python codes in laravel by using `composer require symfony/process` library? Do you have any knowledge about it?